# Objeto JavaScript a Json node red

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Estoy intentando pasar un javascript object generado por mi red node a formato json.

El script object que se obtiene es un hora y minutos que se escribe en pantalla por ejemplo “13:02”

Deseo obtener un json tipo `{"hora" : "hh:mm"}`
Este es el código:

```
msg.payload = hour+':'+minute;
return msg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si pones este código en una función se genera la hora
y se enviaría como objeto json.
Creo que te puede servir de ejemplo.

```
var now  = new Date()
var hora = now.getHours()
var min  = now.getMinutes()

if(min<10) min='0'+min

msg.payload = {}
msg.payload.hora = hora+":"+min

return msg;
```

el esquema quedaría así.
Como ves en el nodo Debug aparece la hora como indicas.
[image: esquema node-red de la respuesta]

Codigo completo del ejemplo.
(Menu => importar => clipboard )

```
[{"id":"185041b1.df1276","type":"function","z":"dc1bc631.8d05e","name":"hora","func":"\nvar now  = new Date()\nvar hora = now.getHours()\nvar min  = now.getMinutes()\n\nif(min<10) min='0'+min\n\nmsg.payload = {}\nmsg.payload.hora = hora+\":\"+min\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":245,"y":590,"wires":[["99945ec.52005a"]]},{"id":"cbf7cf99.105718","type":"inject","z":"dc1bc631.8d05e","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":110,"y":590,"wires":[["185041b1.df1276"]]},{"id":"99945ec.52005a","type":"debug","z":"dc1bc631.8d05e","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":true,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":390,"y":590,"wires":[]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
msg.payload = {
"time": hour+':'+minute
}
return msg;
```

Por otro lado se puede usar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este nodo permite pasar de string s JSON y de JSON a string. 
***Respuesta obtenida por [hardillb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504554/hardillb)***